# Angularjs - Format date (13 January 2016)

Tags: angularjs

I have the next date:

```
<p>{{customer.date | date :  "fullDate"}}</p>
```

I would like to have this format: 13 January 2016

I am testing with formats different but dont get it.

How could i do it? thanks,

Comment: what format codes did you try?  you aren't showing any of them here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the AngularJS documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

```
<p>{{customer.date | date :  "dd MMMM y"}}</p>
```